# Counting an already counted column in SQL (db2)

Tags: sql, count, db2

I'm pretty new to SQL and have this problem:

I have a filled table with a date column and other not interesting columns.

`date | name | name2`

`2015-03-20 | peter | pan`
`2015-03-20 | john | wick`
`2015-03-18 | harry | potter`

What im doing right now is counting everything for a date

```
select date, count(*)
from testtable
where date >= current date - 10 days
group by date
```

what i want to do now is counting the resulting lines and only returning them if there are less then 10 resulting lines.
What i tried so far is surrounding the whole query with a temp table and the counting everything which gives me the number of resulting lines (yeah)

```
with temp_count (date, counter) as 
(  
select date, count(*)
from testtable
where date >= current date - 10 days
group by date
    )
select count(*)
from temp_count
```

What is still missing the check if the number is smaller then 10.
I was searching in this Forum and came across some "having" structs to use, but that forced me to use a "group by", which i can't.
I was thinking about something like this :

```
with temp_count (date, counter) as 
(  
select date, count(*)
from testtable
where date >= current date - 10 days
group by date
    )
select *
from temp_count
having count(*) < 10
```

maybe im too tired to think of an easy solution, but i can't solve this so far

Edit: A picture for clarification since my english is horrible
http://imgur.com/1O6zwoh

I want to see the 2 columned results ONLY IF there are less then 10 rows overall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to move your `having` clause to the inner query so that it is paired with the `GROUP BY`:

```
with temp_count (date, counter) as 
(  
    select date, count(*)
    from testtable
    where date >= current date - 10 days
    group by date
    having count(*) < 10
)
select *
from temp_count
```

If what you want is to know whether the total # of records (after grouping), are returned, then you *could* do this:

```
with temp_count (date, counter) as 
(  
    select date, counter=count(*)
    from testtable
    where date >= current date - 10 days
    group by date
)
select date, counter
from (
    select date, counter, rseq=row_number() over (order by date)
    from temp_count
) x
group by date, counter
having max(rseq) >= 10
```

This will return 0 rows if there are less than 10 total, and will deliver ALL the results if there are 10 or more (you can just get the first 10 rows if needed with this also).

Comment: This only gives me the number of resulting lines if there are less then 10, but i want the actual counted lines by date, IF there are all in all less then 10 lines

Comment: do you mean that you want to know how many rows get returned in all (after grouping) and check if it's less than 10?  If so, try the second iteration, although it would be easier to do this client-side, in your webpage or application layer.

Answer (score 0):

In your temp_count table, you can filter results with the WHERE clause:

```
with temp_count (date, counter) as 
(  
select date, count(distinct date)
from testtable
where date >= current date - 10 days
group by date
    )
select *
from temp_count
where counter < 10
```

Comment: The inner query gives me results like "2015-03-20 | 2" multiple times for each unique date. If a count the results of every resulting row i get for example 8 of these rows. I only want to see the actual rows if the overall count is lower then 10. The First query doesn't work, because mycount is not valid and the second one is not what im searching for :(

Comment: i included a picture for further clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
with t(dt, rn, cnt) as (
    select dt, row_number() over (order by dt) as rn
         , count(1) as cnt 
    from testtable 
    where dt >= current date - 10 days 
    group by dt
) 
select dt, cnt 
from t where 10 >= (select max(rn) from t);
```

will do what you want (I think)